How can I get rid of the character prior to a parentheses or a bracket in a string using Bash regex?
Let's assume that I have a string like this:
blah.blah.blah.(hi.there).[la.la].la.ext

what I want is a Bash regex that captures only the first part of the string:
blah.blah.blah

The following regex captures that, but it includes the dot:
[[ "blah.blah.blah.(hi.there).[la.la].la.ext" =~ ([^\[\(]*) ]]

so I have:
'blah.blah.blah.' in ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

Tried multiple ways to get rid of the dot, but with no luck. Is there a regex that gives me that string without the final dot?
The regex should work with square brackets too, like:
'blah.blah.blah.[hi.there].(la.la).la.ext'


If you want "the start of the string, until either a dot-parenthesis or dot-square bracket":
for c in \
    "blah.blah.blah.(hi.there).[la.la].la.ext" \
    "blah.blah.blah.[la.la].(hi.there).la.ext"
do
    [[ "$c" =~ ([^\(\[]*)\.[\(\[] ]]
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done

(this becomes more complicated if brackets without a dot are to be considered normal, non-breaking characters. Or in the contrary, if they are considered separators be there a dot or not)

Take everything (.*) before a period (.) followed by a round opening bracket (():
[[ "blah.blah.blah.(hi.there).[la.la].la.ext" =~ (.*)\.\( ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

Output:

blah.blah.blah


Yes, thanks. But this will not work if instead of an opening parentheses the string has a square bracket, like 'blah.blah.blah.[la.la].(hi.there).la.ext', for example.

@quimm2003 Then change the regex to match either an opening parenthesis, opening bracket or space, like this: [[ "Blah.blah.blah.(blah).blah" =~ (.*)\.(\(|\[| ) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}". I'm sorry, but your question is lacking a lot of details on how we can detect the end of the part you want to match. What happens if we now have { instead of ( or [? Should it behave the same? what will make you stop capturing the beginning part? any char not being a word or a dot?

@quimm2003: Please do not change the question if an answer has already been given. Thank you.

@PatrickJanser I'm sorry. The end of the part I want to match is a dot followed by an opening parenthese or an opening square bracket. Before .( or before .[. So it should behave the same.

@Cyrus I have not changed the title, which specifies that I want to get rid of the character which appears before a parentheses OR a bracket. What I did is to add the bracket in the question too, to clarify what I need. Sorry for that.

@quimm2003 Ok, so, in other terms, it should simply not be a letter. So simply use (.*)\.[^\\w] to capture all the beginning until we match a dot followed by a non-letter char.

With your string in a variable: echo "${variable/.[(|{[]*/}"

@Cyrus yep, that will work, thank you very much.

@PatrickJanser your regex does not work for me: [[ "blah.blah.blah.[hi.there].(la.la).la.ext" =~ (.*).[^\\w] ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" gives me blah.blah.blah.[hi.there].(la.la).la.e

@quimm2003 Oh yes, sorry, Bash doesn't understand \w for word characters, like other regex flavours. You'll have to replace it by (.*)\.[^a-z], where [^   ] is to say "not maching one of these chars", and a-z means all characters from "a" to "z". If your words could contain numbers or other chars, then you'll have to use [^a-z0-9].

You were close:

The following regex captures that, but it includes the dot:
[[ "blah.blah.blah.(hi.there).[la.la].la.ext" =~ ([^\[\(]*) ]]

Just add the . after the capture group parens:
[[ 'blah.blah.blah.(hi.there).[la.la].la.ext' =~ ([^[\(]*)\. ]] &&
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
blah.blah.blah

I remove the \ before [ as it's not necessary and introduces undefined behavior.
